# How to send a tab key event to Enter key event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have attached my code

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 009 Then
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        End If
```

it not working.Please any one help to me

Comment: I don't think that looks like `javascript`. More like VBScript.

Comment: This might help with key detection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752424/detecting-enter-keypress-on-vb-net